# json_encode( json_encode (array) )

Tags: php, json, jqplot

I'm trying to create a PHP script to generate JSON data for a jqplot bubble chart. The jqplot [sample code](http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/bubbleChart.html) requires data in the format

```
var arr = [ 
  [45, 92, 1067, {label:"Alfa Romeo", color:'skyblue'}], 
  etc.
];
```

My script is along the lines of

```
while ...
  array_push(
    $arrBubble, 
    array(
      11, 
      123, 
      1236,
      json_encode(
        array('label' => $car, 'color' => 'skyblue')
      )
  );
} 
echo json_encode($arrBubble);
```

The problem is that the result is

```
[ [11, 123, 1236, "{\"label\":"VW", \"color\":\"skyblue\"}"] ]
```

The double json_encode has encoded the object(?) as a literal string.

What's the best way to work around this?

Comment: Why do you keep the json_encode in the loop then?

Comment: How else can I add the `{label:"Alfa Romeo", color:'skyblue'}` into the array for subsequent inclusion in the required JSON (but without encoding as a string)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason to explicitly have a `json_encode` for one of the values inside the array. When you're using `json_encode`, it'll convert each level of the array as you expect.

```
var_dump(json_encode([
  11, 
  123, 
  1236,
  ['label' => $car, 'color' => 'skyblue']
]));
```

Outputs the structure you want:

```
string(48) "[11,123,1236,{"label":"VW","color":"skyblue"}]"
```

Comment: Fantastically simple, thank you. I knew I was missing something straight-forward. Tested and working.